# React + Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem, and I don't know how to solve it!

I am using react with `material-ui`, the background color of the site is dark and when I put a Date type TextField the icon appears in black which makes it difficult to see!

Does anyone know how I can change the icon color to white?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is my code extract

```
<TextField 
       id="date2" 
       label="Data fim" 
       type="date" 
       className={classes.margRight2}
       value={this.state.EndDate} 
       onChange={this.handleChange('EndDate')} 
       InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }} 
/>
```

Comment: Hi Jose, please provide some code, it's hard to help without it

Comment: Hey! If you want people to help you you should add the code of your Textfield (at least) in your question (using markdowns would be a great idea for that), because their is a lot of way to change style of elements in Mui and we don't know which one would suit you ! Cheers :)

Comment: <TextField
                                id="date2"
                                label="Data fim"
                                type="date"
                                className={classes.margRight2}
                                value={this.state.EndDate}
                                onChange={this.handleChange('EndDate')}
                                InputLabelProps={{
                                    shrink: true,
                                }}
                            />

Answer (score 0):

As I'm checking Material-UI uses SVG icons, so you can change its colour by using the "color" CSS property to the svg tag.

Check this Codesandbox for my solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-date-picker-nnzgv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Pay attention to the styles in "index.html" and the "demo.js" line 60. I assign my datetime picker a class and then I use the svg selector to set the white color.

Hope it helps.